# How to include external JNI bindings in gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, java-native-interface

I'm using Android Studio with gradle.  My project uses a external JNI library that I manage in a separate git project from my Android app.

I know how to create the external jni as a module in my AndroidStudio/gradle project and to specify cmake with a path to the CMakeList.txts file in my gradle build.  The JNI library gets loaded fine in my Java app.  My issue is one of packaging.

The external JNI project includes the C code for the native portion of the library but it also includes the java classes which reference the native services in the jni library.  How do I include these binding classes into my app build.

The only way I've been able to do this is to copy the bindings into my apps jni module directory.  I can't find a way to reference the java bindings that are stored as part of the external JNI repository.  I believe I could probably set up maven repo with the bindings but I'd rather keep it local.

For example:

JNI Library Repository

```
- CMakeLists.txt 1
    - java
        - CMakeLists.txt 2
        - com/example/package/file.java
    - src
        - com_example_package_file.c
```

The CMakeLists.txt 1 file has a

```
    add_library(example SHARED src/com_example_package_file.c)
```

directive.

The CMakeLists.txt 2 file has

```
    add_jar (bindings com/example/package/file.java)
```

If I do a local build within this jni project, I will generate an example.so as well as a bindings.jar.

Now if I have a separate project/repo that will use this JNI, I am trying to figure out how to specify things in the build.gradle files of the app.  This is how I have things set up:

App repository:

```
- build.gradle 1
- settings.gradle
- external
    - build.gradle 2
    - src/main
        - AndroidManifest.xml
        - java/com/example/package/file.java
- app
    - build.gradle 3
```

build.gradle 1 doesn't say much.
settings.gradle has

```
    include ':app', ':external'
```

build.gradle 2 has a

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        path "path-to-JNI-repositories-top-level-CMakeList.txt-file"
    }
```

and build.gradle 3 has a

```
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':external')
    }
```

element.

What I've found is that as long as my external module in my app repository has the JNI bindings in its src/main directory, my app will find the bindings and everything will work fine.  My issue is, I don't want to have a copy of the bindings in my app.  The bindings are really specific to the JNI library and I'd like them only to exist there.

If I don't include a src/main directory in the bindings module the build will complain that there is no AndroidManifest.xml.  If I have a src/main/AndroidManifest.xml but don't have a java subdirectory with the java bindings, then the app build will fail because it cannot find the "import com.example.project.file".

I'm thinking that the answer is some kind of dependencies line in build.gradle (3) that would point to the external jni repo or to a jar file from that build.  The problem there, is that the cmake that gets executed from the externalNativeBuild statements does not appear to generate a jar file (that I can find anywhere).  Again, when I execute cmake in the JNI repo, the jar gets created (because of the add_jar directive), but when cmake is executed as part of the gradle build, it does not seem to get generated and so cannot be referenced in my dependencies.

Has anyone done something similar or do you have any suggestions?

Comment: After a little extra searching, I have found the Jars.
./external/.cxx/Debug/143s6qt0/arm64-v8a/of_core_jni/java/JavaOpenFiles.jar
./external/.cxx/Debug/143s6qt0/arm64-v8a/of_smb_jni/java/JavaSmb.jar

How do I add these to a dependencies statement?  The 143s6qt0 seems generated, and the platform (arm64-v8a) is platform specific.